# How to create a JSON POST job in Azure Scheduler

Tags: json, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-scheduler

I'm used to using Fiddler, so am probably missing something simple, however... I need to create a scheduled job in Azure to POST to an API monthly.  Everything goes well until I try to enter the BODY content:

[image]

When Azure tries to create the job, it returns an error and fails to create it:

> At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list
>   deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug
>   for usage details. (Code: DeploymentFailed)
>
> ```
> Content-Type must be provided with body (Code: BadRequest)
> ```

I can't figure out what's wrong, as clearly the Content-Type *is* there.  Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why are you putting the `Content-Type: application/json` inside Body. Shouldn't that be a header?

Comment: Yes you are totally correct.  I am too used to put everything in one box in Fiddler, and assumed that headers were for authentication.  Anyway you've solved my issue with a mountain of simplicity, for which I am very grateful - thank you.

Comment: If you want to delete the comment and post as an answer, I'll accept and close the question.

Comment: No problem. You can create your own answer and accept it. It's totally fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User error 101.  `Content-Type: application/json` should be applied as a **header**, and not in the body structure:

[image]

Thank you to @Jack Zeng for his comment.